# Autodesk Forge Error trying to access the API online

Tags: c#, jquery, xmlhttprequest, autodesk-forge

I have a problem loading a 3D model on an online server, the error shown is related to accessing the Forge API, locally works smoothly however when mounted on the server or a website is made marks the following error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", then "onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:7".
As I comment, what I find stranger is that, locally, it works. Attached the segment of the code where it displays the error.

```
 function getAccessToken() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", '/api/forge/toke', false); //Address not found
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the issue. When I make the deploy I have to change the url where the request is made for the public or the name of the domain. For example: mywebsite.com/aplication-name/api/forge/token.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code you're running locally and the code you've deployed are really the same?

The `getAccessToken` function doesn't seem to be correct, for several reasons:

- First of all, there seems to be a typo in the URL - shouldn't it be `/api/forge/token` instead of `/api/forge/toke`?
- More importantly, the HTTP request is **asynchronous**, meaning that it cannot return the response immediately after calling `xmlHttp.send()`. You can find more details about the usage of `XMLHttpRequest` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest.
- And finally, assuming that the function is passed to `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer` options, it should return the token using a callback parameter passed to it (as shown in https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/initialization/#example).

With that, your `getAccessToken` should probably look more like this (using the more modern `fetch` and async/await):

```js
async function getAccessToken(callback) {
  const resp = await fetch('/api/forge/token');
  const json = await resp.json();
  callback(json.access_token, json.expires_in);
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much for taking the time to answare my question. I've already found the issue. When I make the deploy I have to change the url where the request is made for the public or the name of the domain. For example: http://mywebsite.com/api/forge/token. In the question I made a mistake when I was writing, thats why it says "toke" instead of "token".